# How to use sorl-thumbnail package together with django-tables2 package?

Tags: django, django-tables2, sorl-thumbnail

I do have a table defined in tables.py that renders a column with recipes images.

```
class ImageColumn(Column):

    def render(self, value):
        return format_html(
            '<img src="static/media/{url}" height="150px", width="150px">',
            url=value
        )


class RecipeTable(tables.Table):

    image = ImageColumn()
    name = Column(linkify=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"
        fields = (
            "image",
            "name",
            "directions",
            "ingredients",
        )
```

Each image has different size and when I render it with fixed height="150px", width="150px", aspect ratio messes up the image. Therefore I thought I could use sorl-thumbnail package to help mi with generating thumbnails, rather then resizing the whole images. It looks like it is not possible to easily use both django-tables2 and sorl-thumbnail since thumbnails are rendered in html template. My template contains only this to render the table:

```
{% render_table table 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html' %}
```

I need to access the cell so that I can use thumbnail template tag where image should be placed.

```
{% thumbnail item.image ‘200x100’ as im %}
    <img src=’{{ im.url }}’>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

The only solution I see could be to edit the bootstrap4.html, but is there a better way? Am I missing something?

Comment: Instead of rendering with fixed height/width, you could use css: `object-fit: cover` that would allow for a fixed size without changing the aspect ratio. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: Thanks. I might do it that way for now. I guess it would be not ideal in terms of performance. Since all images would have to be loaded in full size.